# How to check for row equality and update another column in postgresql?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a table like below:

[image]

As you can see from above, the "transaction-id" column contain the same values for many entries. What I need to achieve is that for all the entries with same "transaction-id", I want the same "rank_value".

The required result is shown below:
[image]

As you can see the empty values in the former table are filled up by in the later one. How can I achieve this using postgresql?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0):

If one row has a value, then you can just use `max()` as a window function:

```
select t.*, max(rank_value) over (partition by transaction_id)
from t;
```

If you want to do this in an `update` in Postgres, then you can do:

```
update t
    set rank_value = tt.rank_value
    from (select transaction_id, max(rank_value) as rank_value
          from t
          group by transaction_id
         ) tt
    where t.transaction_id = tt.transaction_id;
```